# In Protractor test scripts, will we be able to locate elements using by . binding when browser.ignoreSynchronization=true

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, binding, protractor

I'm asking this question coz, the app that I'm testing flows from a non-angular app. I'm my case the whole page is non-angular and it contains a link. On clicking on it opens the new angular view.  The problem that I'm facing is that the app is manually bootstrapped. I even added the ng-app under a div and mentioned that as rootElement in the script. However this is throwing an error saying "unable to synchronize with the page. No injector found. The reason maybe that it's not under ng-app. Later when I turn off the synchronization I can't locate elements using their binding values. 
I've tried most of the workarounds on net and none of them seems to fix this. Could any of please help

Answer (score 1):

Manually bootstrapped apps are a pain. When you turn off browser synchronization you are telling Protractor that Angular is not and will not ever be present. Because by.binding is Angular-only, and there is no Angular present to bind to, that particular locator isn't going to return an element. I use Protractor for non-Angular apps quite often and it works just fine as long as you don't try to use locators that are Angular-specific. Your options are:

1. Test all of the non-Angular stuff manually, then the Angular stuff separately
2. Test everything without the Angular locators

Comment: Currently I've switched off the synchronization when in non-angular side of the page and when I click on the link (which brings the angularjs view in the form of a tool tip) I'm turning the synchronization on.this should work theoretically.. However since the app is manually bootstraped it says unable to sync since no injector found